# Java - Replace specific line in file without copying all data to another file

Tags: java, file, text, replace, line

I have some text file named data.dat. The second line contains a number which I would like to update to another number. The file can get pretty huge so I don't want to create any temporary files and copy over all this data to another file just to change a single line. Is there a way?

Comment: If the replacement is of the same length, then you can overwrite it using a RandomAccessFile. Otherwise you need to copy. It's not really specific to Java, it's how the filesystem works.

Comment: The replacement will increase or a decrease the number, so I imagine if the number goes from say  75 to 215 I wouldn't be able to use RandomAccessFile?
Also, if it's how the filesystem works, then when I open a file in a text editor and change a line, the filesystem still copies the file? I wouldn't think so

Comment: The filesystem itself doesn't copy, a program does. Text editors read the file in to memory, edit it there, and (if changed) write it back out; in most cases to avoid risk of loss they actually write a new file and then safely 'switch' the old file to the new one. Try it with a 'pretty huge' file and see for yourself, preferably with a monitor like `top` on Unix or `procexp` or recent `taskmgr` on Windows. For Unix you can also see the new file has a new inumber; for Windows that's harder to see but you can try playing with attributes.